# rails activerecord _id suffix in property

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

What is the implication of using a "_id" suffix for a field name in active record?

```
  t.string :foo_id
```

Does this always presume that it is a foreign key to "foo" table?

Is it better to use something like

```
  t.string :foo_id_value
```

to avoid ambiguity with rails?

The idea is that this id value has nothing to do with foreign keys and may not necessarily be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You may wind up with a strange validation message.

Given a Rails 3 model with a validation like `validates :foo_id, :presence => true`,
when you leave `foo_id` blank and validate,
then you'll get the message "Foo can't be blank" instead of the expected "Foo id can't be blank".

Comment: Saw this kind of validation error today in a Rails 5 project. Quite surprising.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of convention. In my experience you won't have any problems unless you do `belongs_to :foo`

If you want to avoid ambiguity for other developers, then yes, it's a good idea to avoid it.